# Calling Same mat-sidenav multiple times(Angular)

Tags: angular

In the below code,I am calling **sidenav.toggle** at two times.One at div and at button.
But the sidenav opens only when `div` clicked.The sidenav not opening when I click the button.

Can anyone provide solution for this.

```
<mat-card-content> 
                <div (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="vl" >
                <mat-sidenav-container>
                    <mat-sidenav #sidenav  mode="side">
                       ...
                    </mat-sidenav>
                    <mat-sidenav-content>
                     <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i>
                      </button>
                    </mat-sidenav-content>
                  </div>
</mat-card-content>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Please help me with this

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the click event bubbles up to the div as well, so `toggle()` is called twice. One for the button click listener, and the div click listener. You need to use `.stopPropagation()` to prevent this:

```
<mat-card-content> 
  <div (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="vl" >
    <mat-sidenav-container>
      <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side"></mat-sidenav>
      <mat-sidenav-content>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); sidenav.toggle()">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i>
        </button>
      </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
  </div>
</mat-card-content>
```

Perhaps it's neater to just use a function in your component, but you get the idea